# Conditional bakery problem

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

This question is from QuantGuide(Bakery Boxes):
A bakery manager uniformly at random selects an integer k between 1 and 4, inclusive. He then chooses from k distinct desert types at his shop to create a gift basket consisting of k items. Find the expected number of ways that the manager can create the gift basket.
My Approach:
Let us have the opportunity to select k from 1 to n-1 and the expected value be denoted by $E_{n-1}$. Where $E_1 = 1$. With probability $\frac{n-1}{n}$ we select a number less than n and in that case the expected value is $E_{n-1}$. With probability $\frac{1}{n}$ we select n. In that case, using n distinct deserts are used to make a basket of n items. Total no of ways is $n^n$.
Hence
\begin{equation}
E_n = \frac{n-1}{n}E_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}n^n = \frac{1}{n}(1+2^2+3^3+ \cdots + n^n)
\end{equation}
Using this I'm getting 72

Comment: a) there is no $n$ defined, what does it signify in your ansatz? b) the question is about _the number of different baskets possible_ -- that has nothing to do with $k$ chosen randomly, only $k$ may be 1..4 me think.

Comment: Here we have to select k from 1 to 4.  So I'm checking for the cases of 1 to 2, then 1 to 3 and continuing this trend from 1 to n

Comment: Thus _"chooses from k distinct desert types"_ should read **chooses from $n$ distinct desert types**. Pls confirm.

Comment: It is to choose k distinct desert types from 1 to n. The given n in the question is 4.  For recursive formulation, I'm looking for the expected value from n=1 to n=4

Comment: _"The given n in the question is 4."_ No, where so? Only $k$ is mentioned, but no $n$. For this it's (for me) not apparent/traceable how you get the $72$ options.

Comment: I've looked up your query at [QuantGuide](https://www.quantguide.io/questions/bakery-boxes). There too is no $n$ mentioned.

Comment: Yes it's correct

Comment: Hi @DevanshAgarwal it would be great if we could contact.

Comment: Hey @DevanshAgarwal how do we get in contact?

Comment: I've not yet received a connection request @DevanshAgarwal

Comment: @DevanshAgarwal I'm yet to receive connection request. Can you give your details so that I can send you request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations involve quite a lot of double counting. For eg. consider the case when $k = 2$. Say, the varieties are $d_1$ and $d_2$. There are only $3$ ways to make the basket, i.e., $d_1d_1$, $d_2d_2$, $d_1d_2$. But you are also counting $d_2d_1$ as a separate basket.

> Method 1: Finding the number of baskets case by case:

$1.$ $k = 1$: There is only $1$ basket possible

$2.$ $k = 2$: There are $3$ baskets possible (as explained above)

$3.$ $k = 3$: Three subcases follow here:-

$\quad$ $3.1$ AAA: $3$ baskets ($d_1d_1d_1, d_2d_2d_2, d_3d_3d_3$)

$\quad$ $3.2$ AAB: $6$ baskets (${3 \choose 1} \cdot {2 \choose 1}$)

$\quad$ $3.3$ ABC: $1$ basket ($d_1d_2d_3$)

$4.$ $k = 4$: $5$ subcases follow here:

$\quad$AAAA ($4$), AAAB (${4 \choose 1} \cdot {3 \choose 1} = 12$), AABC (${4 \choose 1} \cdot {3 \choose 2} = 12$), AABB (${4 \choose 2} = 6$), ABCD ($1$).

$\quad$So total baskets in this case = $4 + 12 + 12 + 6 + 1 = 35$

Finally, since each value of $k$ is uniformly picked, we find the expected number of ways to make the basket, $E$, as follows:

$$E = \frac14 \cdot \big( 1 + 3 + 10 + 35 \big) = \frac{49}4 = 12.25$$

> Method $2$: Using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) in combinatorics

For a given $k$, we want the number of non-negative integral solutions to the equation $d_1 + d_2 + ... + d_k = k$, which is given by ${k + k - 1 \choose k-1}$

Hence, $$E = \frac14 \cdot \big[ {1 \choose 0} + {3 \choose 1} + {5 \choose 2} + {7 \choose 3} \big]$$